# Not able to read Array of Addresses in Function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, ethereum-wallet-dapp, remix

```
function approveUsers(address[] users) onlyOwner {
   for(uint i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
       approvedUsers[users[i]] = true; //Mapping {address: bool}
       ApproveUserForPreSale(users[i], approvedUsers[users[i]]); //Event
   }
 }
```

I'm getting a zero length array with this snippet. And if I take users as static array( address[10] users), I get the correct length but the contents are 0(0x0..).

**edit** This is working on Remix Studio as Expected, but not on Ethereum Wallet.

Comment: How do you call `approveUsers`? Is it from javascript or from another solidity contract?

Comment: approveUser is called by deployer of the contract. (Through etherium wallet GUI).

Answer (score 1):

There a re handful of things going on here.

**The main problem**

Your function doesn't return anything. It appears it sets a bit in a `mapping` to true and I would expect that probably works as far as it goes.

** Other problem #1 **

The use of a dynamic array in a function signature means this function will not be able to communicate with other contracts, at this time. Consider a fixed-length signature approach, e.g. 
```
function approveUser(address user) onlyOwner returns(bool success) {
  approvedUsers[user] = true; 
  // event ... 
  return true;
}

** Other problem #2 **

`for i<0; i<unlimited ...` is an anti-pattern that will cease to work when the gas cost exceeds the block gasLimit. The fixed-length approach that deals with one user at a time will resolve this.

The patterns over here may save you some time: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to approve many users at a time. One by one approving all users would be a lot of work and very costly. Any other way I can add multiple entries that would result in mapping. Why can't I even read what is passed.

Comment: It doesn't imply an increase in manual work or great increase in gas cost. It implies that the iteration will be performed by a smart client or server that will make multiple inexpensive calls, not by a single function that will perform a humongous job in one gulp.